# how to know that what Javascript (line & file) is being used on a Web Page

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to find out (in Chrome/FireFox) that which Javascript file (and hopefully line number) is being used on a web page by a specific element?

Thanks

Comment: You mean which javascript uses that element? Javascript could be referencing that element in a large number of different ways (by tagname, id, class, etc).

Comment: Yah, so for e.g, If I click, say a textbox, I need to know which Javascript is being used by it.

Comment: You're looking at it backwards. JS is not used by elements. JS uses elements.

Answer (score 3):

The question is a bit unclear, but I can show you how to watch a particular element for JavaScript interaction in Chrome:

[image]

Then, after you do that, watch as we click the checkbox:

[image]

Some reference for Chrome: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview

Most other browser work in a similar fashion. There are also other ways to find out how JavaScript code is interacting with your page, but you'll need to give me a more specific scenario to answer that.

Comment: I didn't know that Chrome could do this, thanks a ton.